# Which common nouns have a locative?

Tags: declension, case, locative

I recently mentioned to someone the mnemonic I'd learned for the locative: "cities, towns, islands smaller than Rhodes, and *domus* and *rus*". In other words, only the names of cities, towns, and small islands, plus two common nouns, were able to take the locative case.

To my surprise, though, they had learned a different mnemonic, ending in "*domus*, *rus*, and *humus*". And another chimed in that *focus* could also take the locative.

Is there a complete list of common nouns which have commonly-accepted locative forms? (I'm looking primarily for Classical Latin, but earlier or later citations are fine also, so long as the locative wasn't productive at that time.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a complete list, but [Albert Hoefer](https://books.google.com/books?id=x3cNAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA2-PA192&lpg=RA2-PA192&dq=foci+humi+vesperi+luci+ubi+ibi+ruri+romae&source=bl&ots=OPSBmRduJK&sig=lkgOFnUQ5sb07G_UDt0Ti8TOAQA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj37arf7dHUAhXH8j4KHegGAbgQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=foci%20humi%20vesperi%20luci%20ubi%20ibi%20ruri%20romae&f=false) has an extensive one:

"Pronouns":

> ubi, ibi, hic, illic

However, I doubt these are true locatives. See de Vaan on *ubi*:

> **ubi** 'where' [adv.]...PIt. **k<sup>w</sup>u-þ/fei* 'where'. It. cognates: O. **puf**, U. **pufe**, *pufe* [adv.] 'where' < *k<sup>w</sup>u-b/d<sup>h</sup>ei. PIE *k<sup>w</sup>u-d<sup>h</sup>i/-b<sup>h</sup>i 'where.' IE cognates: Skt. *kuha*m OAv. *kuda* 'where'...
>
> Theoretically, *ubi* can reflect **k<sup>w</sup>ub<sup>h</sup>ei* or **k<sup>w</sup>ud<sup>h</sup>ei*. The suffix *-b<sup>h</sup>i would be the PIE ins[trumental] ending, whereas *-d<sup>h</sup>ei could be an Italic innovation.

The long *i* ending on the *ubi* etc. seems to have lead to Hoefer making them all locatives, but I don't know if that holds up.

Common nouns:

> terrae, militiae, viciniae, belli, humi, domi, foci, crastini (die), ruri, tempori, vesperi, and luci

I've yet to come across someone else adding another to any list.

I have to eat crow. Seems plenty of people do add *animi*, though [some](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Silius_Italicus_Punica_Book_9/HuF8EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=locative+use+of+%22animus%22+%22animi%22&pg=PA173&printsec=frontcover) point out it could be a genitive. But sources for it being a locative include [Bennett](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect232), [Oakley](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Commentary_on_Livy_Books_VI_X/m0oTDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=locative%20animus), [Jones & Sidwell](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reading_Latin/triSDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=locative+use+of+%22animus%22+%22animi%22&pg=PA172&printsec=frontcover), and [Duckworth](https://www.google.com/books/edition/T_Macci_Plauti_Epidicus/f0zWCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=locative+use+of+%22animus%22+%22animi%22&pg=PA188&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Very interesting! I've never thought of *ubi* and *ibi* as having cases; what distinguishes a locative *ubi* from a non-locative *ubi*? (Or is it the locative case of some other pronoun?)

Comment: Old Latin also had *senati* 'in the senate', whether that's relevant or not.

Comment: You missed a i in "militae", it has to be "militiae". What about the following words in the article: noctu, lucu, die? Are they not important here?

Comment: Or are those words just never used?

Comment: @Cyb3rKo I always took those to be ablative of time rather than a proper locative. For comparison, *domus*'s locative is *domi* or rarely (per A&G) *domui*, but as far as I can tell isn't *domo* or *domu*, though at some point it becomes difficult for them to be distinguished.

Comment: Hmm. i just realized e.g. "noctu and locu" don't even match the genitive or ablative, so I also wouldn't add it. And "die" is already there in connection to crastini...
I think I found another one while doing further research, what about "animi" (from animus).

Comment: @Cyb3rKo Do you have a citation for a locative use of animus? Makes sense, but I can't remember if I ever saw it.

Comment: @cmw No, sorry. I haven't ever seen it, but I found it online somewhere in a latin wiki or something.

Comment: @cmw I found an example in Vergils Aeneis (Verse 529): `At non infelix animi Phoenissa, [...].` Our school book says it's an locative and it actually also makes sense to translate it with that.

Comment: @Cyb3rKo I doubt that. It's actually a regular genitive, and there are other examples of felix/infelix taking a genitive in poetry. Look at section II beta here: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfelix1

Comment: @cmw Oh ok, but our book says that and I was fine with that.

Comment: @Cyb3rKo Validation for you!

Answer (score 2):

I would add other two words now crystallised as adverbs: diu (during the day) is the old locative for dies-diei and noctu (at night) which is the analogic locative for nox-noctis. See the expression "diu noctuque". The locative was intended to express not only spatial position but also a temporal one.

Comment: Great answer, but a bit surprising to me. Could you add a reference? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can check thic thread https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/11024/dies-and-the-fifth-declension where you can find an explanation of the common origin of the words Deus, Zeus and Dies.

Comment: In here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjC1snMys2CAxWpqf0HHWWRDEUQFnoECBUQAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.classics.unibo.it%2FDidattica%2FLatBC%2FPlauto_vari.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1YFraeveAH_s2OROSgOURr&opi=89978449 (it is a webiste from the University of Bologna, Italy): Plauto, Anfitrione, arg. II. It is in italian: Page 6 the note explaining "hac noctu" mentions that noctu is the analogic form from diu, old locative of dies

Answer (score -3):

Aren't you confusing the idea of 'motion to' with that of actual location?

'Motion to' usually has *ad* + accusative, the exceptions being those in various mnemonics similar to those you quote: cities, towns, small islands, *domus*, *rus* and *humus* (I've never come across *focus* in such a list, but wouldn't rule it out). Thus, *Romam* and NOT *ad Romam* (which means 'near Rome') 'to Rome', and so on. The critical size of the island of Rhodes is questionable, and my guess is that using *ad* depended entirely on the writer's idea of an island's importance.

The locative simply indicates, as you might expect, *place where*,  a position without the idea of motion to it. It takes its form regularly from a genitive or ablative, according to declension, for which the rules are to be found in any elementary grammar. *Romae* means 'at Rome'; *Athenis*, 'at Athens'.

There are a few irregularities to be learnt, such as *domi* for 'at home' (where *domus*, the 4th Decl. genitive might have been expected) and *militiae*, 'in battle' or 'on the battlefield'. Such a list as you ask for would probably be limited to the few exceptions of whatever mnemonic (or maybe aide-memoire?) you choose.

[Edit following responses]:

I'm quite baffled by the responses (below) to this answer. No noun "takes" a locative, but it can certainly can adopt a locative form (e.g. *Romae*), where appropriate, to indicate a "place where" — including those on Draconis's list. Motion towards a place is quite a different thing, usually indicated by *ad* (sometimes *in*) + accusative, but there are exceptions where the preposition is omitted: these are listed in (and are the purpose of) Draconis's mnemonic, and in these cases the preposition, if used, indicates proximity: *ad Romam*, for instance, means 'near Rome'

Comment: Sorry, but where is Draconis confusing anything? Most certainly you can have *Romae*, "at Rome."

Comment: @cmw The mnemonics are simply for memorising which nouns are exempt from being preceded by _ad_  when 'motion to' is indicated. Surely nothing to do with use of the locative? (And _Romae_ is there in the second paragraph).

Comment: @TomCotton I learned the mnemonic as "nouns that take the locative", since to the best of my knowledge the locative is only used for such nouns (the same nouns which use bare accusative for motion toward, and bare ablative for motion from). For e.g. "Italia" I would use *ad* for motion toward, *ab* for motion from, and *in* for place where, never a locative. I may very well be wrong on this, in which case that would make a good answer.

Comment: @TomCotton I don't think that's accurate. The nouns he listed are ones that take a locative: *domi*, *ruri*, *Romae*, and *Rhodi* all are locatives, with few others (*foci* and *humi* as his acquaintance mentioned, *militiae* as you did) not part of his mnemonic. I don't think the accusative of motion is so limited.

Comment: I'm quite baffled by these responses. No noun "takes" a locative, but can adopt a locative form, where appropriate, to indicate a "place where" — including those on your list. Motion towards a place is quite a different thing, usually indicated by _ad_ + accusative, but there are exceptions where the preposition is omitted, listed in (and the purpose of) Draconis's mnemonic, and in these cases the preposition, if used, indicates proximity: _ad Romam_, for instance, means 'near Rome'.

Comment: You've been misinformed. The locative case was a real case that just happened to stop being productive. See Sihler §255 and 256.11. This is entirely unrelated to motion towards with *ad*. It's specifically "place where," and no, those aren't genitives or ablatives you're encountering, they're remnants of an unproductive case called the "locative."

Comment: This is becoming tiresome. Of course the locative was a real case!. It remained so, and in use, but was excluded from the set of cases that are recognised in standard tables of accidence. There are rules for its formation if its use is required.  It's my point _exactly_ that it's unrelated to motion towards with _ad_. I'll say it just once more, and then I'll stop : Draconis's lists are merely of nouns that aren't preceded by _ad_ when motion to them is indicated. This has _nothing to do with the locative case!_

Comment: @TomCotton While that may be the case, *it is also the case that Draconis' list is for nouns that take the locative (place which) in addition to *in + abl*. You are simply mistaken that this thread has *anything* to do with motion at all.

Comment: To show you where your confusion lies, see [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vw49AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (@Draconis), but I thought the question was "**What nouns other than some place names have attested locatives?**" and any discussion of motion is a sidetrack.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta (wearily) I don't question the use of locatives. For one last time, Draconis's list is simply of situations in which no preposition precedes the accusative when motion is indicated. As a teaching aid, that is what it was intended for. They are, certainly, which I have said more than once, also nouns which have useful locative forms. TAGB.