# "Condere vaginae gladium" – locativus?

Tags: dictionary, case, locative

Salvete congerrones eruditissimi,

modo legi in [lexico Latino-Germanico a Henrico Georges confecto](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/-/Hauptseite) (opus Germanicum illi a Lewis & Short conscripto simile atque satis compar) sub lemmate «vagina» [verba haec](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/vagina+%5B1%5D?hl=Lokativ):

> condere vaginae (Lokativ) gladium

⋯ quae Aurelio Prudentio Clementi, clarissimo auctori Christiano, ascribuntur. *Lokativ*, ut certe, sodales acutissimi, iam conieceratis, casum locativum significat. Hoc si verum esset, verbum *vagina* [illi tabulae](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/which-common-nouns-have-a-locative) addere possemus, in qua verba communia continentur, quae cum locativo saltem interdum inveniuntur. Quod mirum mihi videretur. Habetne res se ita?

Nonne vero propius videtur *vaginae* in hoc loco dativum esse, quippe cum Georges ipse, [sub lemmate «condo»](http://www.zeno.org/Georges-1913/A/condo?hl=dat), affirmet id verbum cum dativo inveniri, quaestioni respondens: «quem in locum?» (numquam quidem apud Ciceronem). Sed verum est verbum *condo* locativo casui nonnumquam coniunctum esse, e.g. «aliquid domi suae conditum iam putare». Verbo *domus* quidem in illa tabula locum esse nemo dubitat.

Quid sentitis?

Comment: Interrogata tua legere semper valde fruor, mi congerro acutissime!

Comment: Mihi quoque dubia videtur haec sententia Georgii: si enim ita esset, possemus certe dicere e.g. *Gladium vaginae est*, quod haud Latinum puto. (Si de casibus disseritur, ut pediculum eligam, nonne scribendum erat *in lexico Latino-Germanico ... opere Germanico*, etc.?)

Comment: Si *condo* cum dativo casu quaestioni respondens: «quem in locum?» . Quid igitur inter dativum et locativum casūs sit, nisi quam nomina eorum?

Comment: @TKR adde «quod est opus etc.» ;-)

Comment: Neue and Wagener 1902, Band 2, p. 642 **C. Lokativ. 8. I. 1. Substantivische Lokative** https://archive.org/details/formenlehrederla02neueuoft/page/642/mode/2up

Comment: cf. Magnus Frisch (Frisch 2020: 228) “*uaginae* ist hier Dativ der Richtung bws. des Ziels nach Verben der Bewegung (vgl. Lease 1895: 23-24 §59, Lavarenne 1933: 88 §172 u. Burton 2004: 13)” https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110630831-011/html

Comment: Lavarenne 1933 “poétique et postclassique”, **datif de direction**; Hofmann and Szantyr 1965/2016 *Lateinische Grammatik Bd. 2: Lateinische Syntax und Stilistik* §70 (Dativ des Zieles bzw. der Richtung), pp. 100-101; Stotz 1998 *Handbuch zur lateinischen Sprache des Mittelalters Bd. 4: Formenlehre, Syntax und Stilistik*, pp. 257-258 (§16 Dativ des Ziels, der Richtung)

Comment: @AlexB. Quam mirum tot auctores eum ipsum locum iam intuiti esse. Recentiores Latinitatis periti in ea sententia esse videntur, ut *vaginae* casus dativus sit in hoc loco. Quod libenter audio, cum mihi assentiantur, et invitus audio, cum illa tabula augeri non iam posse videatur.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with TKR's comment above that *vaginae* {is not/cannot be} marked with locative case. I share your view that, to the extent that this expression (*condere vaginae gladium*) is attested, *vaginae* is probably a dative.

In fact, it is worth noting that some eminent philologists have claimed that in examples like the following one from Horace *proprio horreo* is a dative, instead of a non-prepositional ablative phrase, which is often found in poetry. For example, your compatriot Heinrich Düntzer interpreted *proprio horreo*, which also coappears with the verb *condere*, as a directional dative (Germ. "**Dat des Zieles**"): see his comment on *horreo* [here](https://books.google.es/books?id=FIr-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&lpg=PA30&dq=horreo%20Dat.%20Zieles%20Heinrich%20D%C3%BCntzer&source=bl&ots=qgeYyzZcQd&sig=ACfU3U0dFBUgUSUY5rCvpcrIf37s6NXmkQ&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp8OuPwcnvAhVI3IUKHT_zAgsQ6AEwAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=horreo%20Dat.%20Zieles%20Heinrich%20D%C3%BCntzer&f=false). My hunch is that (again, to the extent that the expression *condere vaginae gladium* is attested), it could be the case that Aurelius Prudentius Clemens, an egregius Christian poet, also interpreted (some of) these non-prepositional ablative phrases typically found in poetry (e.g., in Horace, Virgil, Ovid, et al.) as datives.

> si **proprio** *condidit* **horreo** / quicquid de Libycis verritur areis. (Hor. *Od*. 1, 1, 9-10)