# Is any word attested in both vocative and locative?

Tags: declension, example-request, case, locative, vocative

Both the vocative and the locative are pretty rare cases, and not found in all kinds of words.
Is there any word that is attested in both cases in classical Latin?
I prefer the vocative to be distinct from the nominative, if possible.

I can easily conceive of situations where those two cases might arise, but I'm not sure if it has actual ever happened in the literature.
The two attestations need not be in the same work or the same author.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Corinthus

City names regularly have locative forms (identical to the genitive singular), and it is not too rare for them to be addressed with a vocative, which takes the regular ending *-e* if the name is in the second declension and non-neuter.

An example from Classical Latin is *Corinthus,* which appears in the vocative *Corinthe* in Publius Ovidius Naso, *Tristia* 3.8.4:

> nunc ego Medeae vellem frenare dracones,
>
> quos habuit fugiens arce, **Corinthe,** tua;

The locative *Corinthi* can be found in Marcus Tullius Cicero, *De Lege Agraria* 2.90.1:

> Verum arbitrabantur **Corinthi** et Carthagini, etiam si senatum et magistratus sustulissent agrumque civibus ademissent, tamen non defore qui illa restituerent atque qui ante omnia commutarent quam nos audire possemus

Comment: I was trying to think of a second-declension city that fit this criteria, but Corinth didn't spring to mind. Good one!

Answer (score 9):

> I prefer the vocative to be distinct from the nominative, if possible.

One word that does have a distinct locative and a distinct vocative is:

> **animus**

The vocative is [plentiful](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=anime+mi&first=1) in both Plautus and Terence, where's it's usually used to address someone else, rather than one's own mind.

It's use in the locative seems to occur in certain expressions, and I don't know I always knew it was a locative when reading (as opposed to a genitive), but the [grammars (1)](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/bennett.html#sect232) [indicate (2)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Eton_Latin_Grammar/eq0BAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=locative+use+of+%22animus%22+%22animi%22&pg=PA251&printsec=frontcover) that it is indeed a locative (and it makes sense as such).

Comment: Hmmm, it's not on [The Locative List](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/which-common-nouns-have-a-locative).

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Ha! Well, I'll have to update that now.

Comment: FWIW, here is a relevant entry in [A&G (358)](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/genitive-special-verbs). "The apparent genitive animī (really locative)". in which it lists also *mentis* as a locative.

Comment: @d_e I wonder if *mentis* was modeled after *animi*? Needs more study, as my old professor used to say.

Comment: @cmw, I've just looked-up *De Rerum Natura* commentary by William Leonard on 1.36, He seems to have *animi* as genitive "to specify a respect in which the action of the verb is true". and gives also *mentis* -- but also *sermonis* in "sermonis fallebar" in Plautus. Frankly I can't see how *sermonis* be taken as locative;; those *animi*, *mentis*, *sermonis* seem to be instrumental.

Comment: @d_e The standard locative would be with an -i (like *Carthagini*), so neither *mentis* or *sermonis* should work. It could be some confusion of the forms with the other forms created on a mistaken analogy. Or perhaps the *animi* is really a genitive after all.

Answer (score 8):

### Domus

This doesn't fulfill your second criterion, because the vocative looks exactly the same as the nominative (i.e. it's not second declension masculine). But it's famously one of the common nouns that can appear in the locative, and does so frequently; here's Cicero (*Pro Quinctio*):

> Quasi **domi** nummos haberet, ita constituit Scapulis se daturum.
> *As if he had the money **at home**, he thus made a formal contract to pay the Scapulae.*

And it's also common enough to be addressed metaphorically; here's Cicero again (or rather an unknown tragedian he's quoting) in *De Officiis* I:

> Odiosum est enim, cum a praetereuntibus dicitur: "**o domus antiqua**, heu, quam dispari dominare domino!" quod quidem his temporibus in multis licet dicere.
> *For it is unpleasant when it is said by passers-by: "**oh, old house**, alas, what an unfitting master masters you now!"—which indeed, in these times, can be said about many of them.*

Comment: With *domus*, you never know which ending it will be, so it's good to have an attestation. No *dome* in the Packhum corpus, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

Just lucky first search attempt:

> eheu! quam fatuae sunt tibi, Roma, togae! (Mart.Ep.10.19.4).

There are actually [many more instances](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%2C%20Roma%2C) of Rome being addressed.